# Understanding class-wide variables that should be tied to object instances

Tags: python, oop

Here is a class that assigns a symbol to a player. It should accept a move and add the move to the existing repository of moves of the player.

```
class Player:
   ...:     positions = []
   ...:     def __init__(self,symbol):
   ...:         self.symbol = symbol
   ...:     def move(self,position):
   ...:         self.position = position
   ...:         self.positions.append(self.position)
```

My problem is that positions is behaving "globally" in the sense that it is not tied to an object instance, to demonstrate:

```
>>>a = Player('x')
>>>b = Player('y')
>>>a.move(1)
>>>b.positions
[1]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say,

```
class Player:
    positions = []
```

`positions` will be a class variable and the same object is used by all the instances of the class. You can confirm by this

```
player1, player2 = Player(), Player()
print player1.positions is player2.positions    # True
print Player.positions is player1.positions     # True
```

If you want to create instance variables (separate `positions` variable for each and every instance of `Player`), you can create that in `__init__` function. It is a special initializer function, which gets the current actual object as the first parameter. You can create `positions` variable and attach it to that object like this

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.positions = []

player1, player2 = Player(), Player()
print player1.positions is player2.positions    # False
```

Here, `self` refers to the newly constructed object and you are creating a new variable in that object by `self.positions` and you are initializing it with an empty list by

```
self.positions = []
```

So, whenever you create a new instances of `Player`, `self` will refer to the new instance created and new variable `positions` will be created on every instance, which means separate `positions` variable for each and every instance.

And whenever `move` is called, you don't have to create a new `position` variable on `self`. Instead you can do this

```
def move(self, position):
    self.positions.append(position)
```

If you are using Python 2.x, its better to use new style classes, like this

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.positions = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare it inside the `__init__` method. Anyhting declared outside the `__init__` method will be a class attribute and will be shared between all instances of the class.

You don't have to pass it anything:

```
class Player: 
   ...:     def __init__(self,symbol):
   ...:         self.symbol = symbol
                self.positions = []
   ...:     def move(self,position):
   ...:         self.position = position
   ...:         self.positions.append(self.position)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to make class variable into instance variable, which will bind only to a particular instance.

Currently, `positions = []` is class variable which can access from all the instances. So, you better assign to a particular instance variable.

You can do that by define inside `__init__()`, which will call when you create an instance of that class.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you'd also want to initialize self.position to None in init, lest you hit this error:

```
p = Player() 
p.position 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Player instance has no attribute 'position'
```

So you'd want this:

```
class Player(object):     # making it a new-style class
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self.position = None
```

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that positions is behaving "globally" in the sense that it is not tied to an object instance, to demonstrate

Yes, that is by design of the language. Python follows a rule that is not like some other modern languages with OO support, but is very simple and easily understood: *everything you write inside the `class` block describes a part of the class*. (Remember, in Python, everything is an object - including the classes themselves.)

So I do not really understand what the problem is. You clearly already know how to make things that belong to the instances (hint: you are already doing it with `symbol`). You may just need to re-think your design and be clearer about what you *intend* to happen.